# Cookies expiring too quickly enough in c# asp.net webpages

Tags: c#, cookies, webforms

For some reason my cookies don't last as long as they should, usually within 15 min a user would have to log back on. I am using webform login and when a user logs in I set the cookie like this.

```
   HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserName", "Joe");
   cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(5);    
   HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

When I read the cookie this is what I do

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserName"] != null && Request.Cookies["UserName"].value == "Joe")
```

This is what is on my web.config file for authentication, everyone gets bounced back to the loginpage.aspx in less than 1 hour

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="LoginPage" path="/" loginUrl="/LoginPage.aspx" defaultUrl="Index.aspx"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <!-- Deny all anonymous users-->
  <allow users="*"/>
  <!-- Allow all authanticated users-->
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is timeout works. To fix that add attribute `timeout="0"` to your  element. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I tried 0 but doesn't work, however I set it to 5760 or 4 days, I will test this for  a while, most likely this was the issue as it was timing out under an hour and the default value is 30 for what I read in the MSDN docs.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks myroman I've been working on this issue on and off for days!

Comment: @Eliseo That's good! Don't hesitate to accept the answer, btw